# What filter should be used for date field in views

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am building a view for showing upcoming events.

I have my own content type with CCK field with format  Date (Unix timestamp)  and widget as Pop-up calendar. All works fine, but i views i don't know how to filter it out. I have shown the filter criteria in a screeshot and i don't know what to give in the value field.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the value field you can use the PHP [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. So for example you select `Is greater than` and you put `-7 days` in the value field and your view will restrict to contents from 7 days ago.

Also a smoother solution for the end user is to expose this filter and they will be able to use a popup calendar to restrict the view.

Comment: i tried it and it did not work. The sql looks like AND (field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value >= '-7 days') . Is this fine ? Its taking it as text.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your screenshot, I created a test field date timestamp and it display either a select list to choose a date or a relative field where I can put `-7 days`, see http://i.imgur.com/G0H8D.png Have you done any specific configuration ?

Comment: I redid my configurations and now i am getting the options you said. Earlier there must be some problem.

Answer (score 8):

You need to activate the date_views module to see the filters appearing in the Views module interface.